# smtp server returns no auth methods

Tags: email, smtp, telnet

I am trying to set up my university smtp server with wanderlust/emacs, and on getting a repeated error decided to have a look via telnet.

the only trouble is, knowing next to nothing about smtp, I can't understand the output:

```
telnet pod51016.outlook.com 587
Trying 157.56.253.22...
Connected to pod51031.outlook.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 DBXPR06CA012.outlook.office365.com Microsoft ESMTP MAIL Service ready at Tue, 30    Sep 2014 16:44:11 +0000
ehlo test
250-DBXPR06CA012.outlook.office365.com Hello [129.234.0.21]
250-SIZE 78643200
250-PIPELINING
250-DSN
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-STARTTLS
250-8BITMIME
250-BINARYMIME
250 CHUNKING
```

I had expected to see an auth line as `250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN` --- II am  just missing something? How do I see what authentication the server supports?

Alternatively, I have it working with thunderbird, so if anyone knows how to extract it from prefs.js that would do.

many thanks, and apologies for the lack of specificity in the question,

John

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The server requires you to use establish a secure connection: Use STARTTLS, and the auth methods will appear.

You can test this with openssl:

```
openssl s_client -starttls smtp -connect server:587
```

Comment: Thankyou very much; I can now connect to the server, but I get no response from `ehlo test` (just sits there); the last 3 lines are `---
250 CHUNKING
ehlo test` then  nothing.... Any ideas? Am I simply misusing s_client?

Comment: okay, looks like the server isn't returning anything... testing with smtp.gmail.com works a expected: `ehlo test
250-mx.google.com at your service, [129.234.0.21]
250-SIZE 35882577 etc`

Comment: still not sure how to work, but found out elsewhere to use login; so emacs/wanderlust is now working correctly. If anyone has a moment, I *would* like to know why it isn't working...

Comment: Yeah, add -crlf to the command line I gave you. Some servers are picky about their end of lines.

Comment: Duh... Thankyou very much, that sorts it.